# Finding function minimum over range of arguments

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Let's assume I have:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 10;
```

and a function with signature

```
public double CalculateEntropySplittingOnFeature(List<Sample> samples, int cutOffPoint)
```

I want to find for which integer value between 5 and 0 included my function returns the lowest value. My solution:

```
((List <Integer>) IntStream.range(x, y))
                .stream()
                .min(new Comparator<Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                        return Double.compare(CalculateEntropySplittingOnFeature(samples, o2), CalculateEntropySplittingOnFeature(samples, o1));
                    }
                });
```

But, I feel like there's a better/more elegant(/efficient) solution than generating an IntStream and casting it to list to then stream it again... Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`((List <Integer>) IntStream.range(x, y))` will throw a `ClassCastException`, since an `IntStream` does not implement `List<Integer>`.

Use

```
IntStream.range(x, y).boxed()
```

to get a `Stream<Integer>`.

EDIT :

```
Optional<Integer> min =
    IntStream.range(x, y)
             .boxed ()
             .min ((o1,o2)->Double.compare(CalculateEntropySplittingOnFeature(samples, o2), 
                     CalculateEntropySplittingOnFeature(samples, o1)));
```

Comment: That seems to have done it, thanks :) Overall - any comments on the style/way I approached it?

Comment: @DarioMan Well, you could save some typing by using a lambda expression instead of the anonymous Comparator implementation.

Comment: `.min(Comparator.comparingDouble(o -> CalculateEntropySplittingOnFeature(samples, o))` always mind the “don’t repeat yourself” principle…

Answer (score 2):

You asked for a style suggestion in your comments. I would suggest:

```
Optional<Integer> lowest = IntStream.range(0, 5).boxed()
    .min(Comparator.comparingDouble(n -> calcEntropySplittingOnFeatures(samples, n)));
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by the other answers, you can convert an `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>` by invoking `boxed()` on it. However, you can do the operation without boxing, when you consider that `min(Comparator)` is just a short-cut for `reduce(BinaryOperator.minBy(Comparator))`. You can re-implement the same operation for `int` values:

```
OptionalInt result=IntStream.range(x, y).reduce((a,b)->
    CalculateEntropySplittingOnFeature(samples, a)<=
    CalculateEntropySplittingOnFeature(samples, b)? a: b);
```

Since this doesn’t look as concise as using `Comparator.comparingDouble(…)`, you may use a helper method in the spirit of `BinaryOperator.minBy(Comparator.comparingDouble(…)))`:

```
public static IntBinaryOperator minBy(IntToDoubleFunction f) {
    return (a,b) -> f.applyAsDouble(a)<=f.applyAsDouble(b)? a: b;
}
```

and use it as

```
OptionalInt result=IntStream.range(x, y)
    .reduce(minBy(i -> CalculateEntropySplittingOnFeature(samples, i)));
```